# How to freeze rotation Y of an object

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

Anyone have any idea,
When we are **manipulating object** how to **freeze rotation Y** of an object.

Comment: Can you give more details?
What do you mean by manipulating object?

Answer (score 1):

you might be interested in MRTK [Constraint Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/constraint-manager?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#fixeddistanceconstraint)